# Why would Dumbledore and McGonagall carry Colin Creevey with their arms?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, minerva-mcgonagall

When Colin Creevey gets petrified in *The Chamber Of Secrets*, Harry sees Dumbledore and McGonagall bringing him in the hospital wing.

He describes them as if they were carrying a statue.

**Why would Dumbledore and McGonagall, pretty old (and thus physically weak) but pretty skilled wizards, resort to the inconvenience of carrying things like petrified people by hand instead of using magic to lift them?**

Using magic would seem both safer for the carrier and for the carried.

Comment: Note that the classic answer "because magic" doesn't really work in that case ;)

Comment: To avoid triggering any nasty, magic related traps/effects. Given that they don't know what caused the damage, potentially anything could make it worse, but using muggle methods seem less likely to be a risk

Comment: It also shows a level of compassion. Despite him being petrified, and potentially dangerous, they're holding Colin because he's a *child* who has been hurt. This sends a powerful message to the heir of Slytherin that Hogwarts will look after those who may get hurt, even at a risk to their own lives.

Comment: @Flooks Tell that to Katie Bell when she took the locket from Draco in Half Blood Prince.

Comment: Perhaps it was a sign of care and respect, why would they have treated him like a piece of luggage?

Comment: I think the answer is the compassion side of things! I'm sure they don't levitate babies just to save their arms!

Comment: @Fatalize Does, "Because science," work?

Comment: @Longshanks some how it feels the writer probably didn't put that much thought into that scene

Comment: I feel like the answer is just 'Because they're human'..... but i think it needs expanding.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because there was no need to. We might guess that the attack occured very close to the hospital wing, since McGonagall and Dumbledore quickly thought that Colin wanted to visit Harry:

> "Another attack," said Dumbledore. "Minerva found him on the stairs."
>
> "There was a bunch of grapes next to him," said Professor McGonagall.
>   "We think he was trying to sneak up here to visit Potter."

What is more, they might have not had their wands with them. Dumbledore claims he was on the way to the kitchen for something to drink, he didn't need a wand for that:

> "Yes," said Professor McGonagall. "But I shudder to think... If Albus
>   hadn't been on the way downstairs for hot chocolate - who knows what
>   might have--"

Finally, some pure speculation. Maybe Dumbledore insisted on not using magic for the traces not to be erased. We learn in the Half Blood Prince that every use of magic leaves some trail.

> Dumbledore was standing in the middle of the cave, his wand held high
>   as he turned slowly on the spot, examining the walls and ceiling.
>
> "Yes, this is the place," said Dumbledore.
>
> "How can you tell?" Harry spoke in a whisper.
>
> "It has known magic," said Dumbledore simply.

It is possible that Dumbledore wanted to return to the stairway that night and further investigate the place, looking for some clues.

Comment: Dumbledore probably had his wand with him. Otherwise, McGonagall's statement doesn't make as much sense (questionable how much could Dumbledore do without his wand?)

Comment: If I was a wizard, I'd carry my wand everywhere. I'd probably get a holster grafted to my arm.

Comment: @neverendingqs, Dumbledore didn't *do* anything, though.  Colin was already out of danger, actually; he was petrified, so he couldn't have been killed by the basilisk's gaze afterward.  But McGonagall didn't know that.  (And being there all night with an unknown menace around wouldn't sound very safe.)

Comment: @neverendingqs, McGonagall might have thought that Dumbledore has a wand. She also could have imagined the attacker thought the same when he/she noticed Dumbledore was coming. If the Headmaster actually had a wand with him is another thing.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Get an Assassins Creed style Hidden Wand for greater effect... and for cool/awesome points.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Ya! From the wrist. I think I actually saw someone it the movies do that with their wand...

Comment: Follow up question — Why would Dumbledore resort to the inconvenience of walking all the way down to the kitchen to get hot chocolate, instead of the million magic ways he could have gotten it? :)

Comment: @anotherdave: For example, in order to have a pleasant chat with the house elfs.

Comment: *"We learn in the Half Blood Prince that every use of magic leaves some trail."* I would say we learned that in Goblet of Fire, when they charm Harry's wand to reveal it's last spell.

Comment: @fredsbend There we only learn about the traces magic leaves in wands, not the traces in enchanted objects.

Answer (score 34):

Dumbledore might be old, but he certainly isn't physically infirm. Someone capable of swimming a hundred yards in "icy water" would certainly have the strength to lift and carry a small boy several tens of feet.

> *‘Then take off your Invisibility Cloak – there is no need for it now – and let us take the plunge.’*
>
> *And with the sudden agility of a much younger man, Dumbledore slid
> from the boulder, landed in the sea and began to swim, with a perfect
> breaststroke, towards the dark slit in the rock face, his lit wand
> held in his teeth. Harry pulled off his Cloak, stuffed it into his
> pocket and followed.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>

Comment: While this adequately counters one of the OP's reasons why Dumbledore would not carry Colin Creevey, it does not explain why the choice was made to carry him rather than levitate him. In other words, it explains why the two possibilities, carry/not carry, are not as unequal as the OP has suggested, but does not explain why carrying was the better choice, or even propose just that the method chosen was a spur-of-the-moment  decision that happened to go one way, despite other, possibly better, solutions.

Comment: @Makyen - Invalidating the question is a perfectly sound way of answering :-)

Comment: @Valorum - Yes, invalidating the question is a valid way to answer, but this does not invalidate the question. It invalidates one assumption leading to the reason the question was asked, but it does not invalidate the actual question of why carry instead of levitate. Specifically, "Why would Dumbledore and McGonagall carry Colin Creevey with their arms?"

Comment: @Makyen - The question suggests that it would be inconvenient. This answer suggests that it would be trivial, and probably easier than trying to maneuver an object using magic.

Comment: @Valorum - The answer does suggest carrying is less difficult than the OP has assumed. It does not address where that puts things as to the relative difficulty of levitating vs. carrying. The answer says Dumbledore *could* carry a small boy. It does not address why he *would* do so instead of using levitate. Note that the question also implies that it took both teachers to bring Colin Creevey into the hospital wing. That supposition implies that actually carrying Colin Creevey was non-trivial (requiring two people), which is contrary to the argument that doing so was trivial.

Comment: Wel, if you want to bang his head on things, you *could* levitate him.

Comment: @Valorum Perhaps include that in your answer then; even if it's implicit _I_ didn't notice it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - It's already in [TBear's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/154044/20774) below.

Comment: @Makyen [Just because they could use magic, it doesn't mean they had to whip out their wands for every little thing](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=p2swDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=JUST+BECAUSE+YOU%27RE+ALLOWED+TO+USE+MAGIC+NOW,+YOU+DON%27T+HAVE+TO+WHIP+YOUR+WANDS+OUT+FOR+EVERY+TINY+LITTLE+THING!%27&source=bl&ots=G9D5LH0YWG&sig=2NDE0jbFnB9k4siR9d-y5fuGz9w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicx6X5y8TSAhWEAcAKHTbECHsQ6AEISTAF#v=onepage&q=JUST%20BECAUSE%20YOU'RE%20ALLOWED%20TO%20USE%20MAGIC%20NOW%2C%20YOU%20DON'T%20HAVE%20TO%20WHIP%20YOUR%20WANDS%20OUT%20FOR%20EVERY%20TINY%20LITTLE%20THING!'&f=false).

Answer (score 18):

First of all, **we know that human levitation is possible** and known. In The Prizoner of Azkaban, we see Sirius Black use *Mobilicorpus* on Snape's unconcious body to levitate it away from the Shrieking Shack, bumping his head intentionally along the way. It is safe to assume that between Dumbledore and McGonagall, one of them should have known the spell, though we (the audience) had never seen it at that point in the series.

> *Getting back into the tunnel was difficult. Lupin, Pettigrew and Ron
> had to turn sideways to manage it; Lupin still had Pettigrew covered
> with his wand. Harry could see them edging awkwardly along the tunnel
> in single file. Crookshanks was still in the lead. Harry went right
> after Sirius, who was still making Snape drift along ahead of them; he
> kept bumping his lolling head on the low ceiling. Harry had the
> impression Sirius was making no effort to prevent this.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban</sup></sub>

Second, the source and nature of Colin's curse was unknown, and so they would have likely sought to err on the side of caution. **Any magic performed on him could have caused further damage to him**, or to the caster. Since the Hospital Wing was so close, they would have wanted to get Colin into Madame Pomfrey's expert hands as soon as they could without exacerbating the situation.

My third thought is a bit more speculative, but keeping their wands free (not being used on a continuous spell) means that **they would have been able to defend themselves against whatever attacked Colin**. This argument is a bit more difficult to defend as their hands would have been occupied, but wand in hand while carrying the boy would have still afforded them the ability to cast a shield charm. Casting *Mobilicorpus* could have made their reactions a tad slower.

Lastly, in situations of high stress, **many wizards resort to muggle practices**. Harry Potter and George Weasley get in a fist fight (*muggle dueling*) with Draco Malfoy after a quidditch match when Draco insulted both of their families. It is possible that the situation with Colin Creevey was dire enough that thought of spell casting was forgotten in the need to rush him to Hospital Wing.

Comment: This is mostly speculation, but I think it makes the most sense in universe. You don't know what magic hit him, maybe casting another spell on him will cause him to explode or something, like a booby trap.

Comment: "We (the audience) had never seen it", because JKR hadn't thought of it.  **The reason Colin wasn't levitated is because the author didn't think through that detail** (and so many others).

Comment: @Brock JKR did have a bit of a learning curve, and there are some inconsistencies in HP, but our job here isn't to come crashing through the 4th wall and make comments about the author's weaknesses. Constructive comments make connections within the story as it stands and speculate about unwritten parts as if the story were true. Your comment is not helpful in this context.

Comment: No, our job is to answer the question.  The correct answer to this question is that the author didn't think of it.  You can try to retcon some in-universe excuse later, but Occam's razor and plain common sense (and the author's own track record and admissions) put the lie to such malarkey.

Comment: Dude, it's fantasy. Obviously you are correct, but that is not the answer OP or anyone else is looking for. Go ahead and post it as an answer and you will quickly come to the same conclusion.

Comment: @BrockAdams out of all the plot holes there might be, I'm pretty sure 'making something be able to float' probably isn't one of them — give her some credit.

Comment: I mean, they could have just used a *time-turner* to go see what happened...

Comment: @TBear "What are in-universe explanations <question>" and "What are **reasonable** in-universe explanations <question>" are notably different questions. Why [Gadsby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadsby_(novel/)) doesn't contain characters with letter 'e' in name, e.g. 'Kevin'?

Answer (score 15):

**Compassion and respect**

Expanding on my earlier comment, and to draw from other answers, we can all agree that Dumbledore and McGonagal are arguably two of the most magically gifted wizards at Hogwarts. Both fully capable of performing magic that would render having to lift a child a simple task.

However, they are also **teachers**.

They have a responsibility for the safety and health of the students, and would be expected to *care* for one who is ill, injured of unhappy.

Yes, they could have levitated Colin, but IMO if they knew he was safe to hold, then they absolutely would have carried him because of their duty of care as his teacher and responsible guardian.

Comment: Is picking someone up really indicative of compassion? Their duty of care was to get him to the hospital wing, by whatever means.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Yeah - I accept that's open to debate. But I'm sure (will try and find quotes) that McG has expressed a caring nature towards her students. We know Dumbledore can apparate wherever he wants due to the benefits of being headmaster. And anti-apparation can be applied to sections of the castle.  So, if it's a matter of time and they wanted to get there quicker, they could have done.

Comment: Dumbledore being able to Apparate in the castle is only movie-canon (and so, to my mind, not canon at all...), not book-canon. As Demosthenes says, though, they were probably not too far away anyway since Colin was on his way to see Harry.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Noted. And I guess then, if they are so close, does it *really* matter how they move Colin from one place to another? It feels like we're overthinking a very small incident...

Comment: Probably. That's what SSF:SE is there for. :P

Comment: A variant of this ("respect") was my initial reaction as well.  While all the answers have merit, this is my favorite and, given their personalities, the most likely in-universe answer.  I'd give it +2, if I could.

Comment: @DougR. Respect - you're right, and I've added that into my answer.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Re: Dumbledore apparating within the castle.  We know from HBP that Dumbledore can suspend the anti-apparition charm within the castle.  A logical extension of that is that, if he wanted to apparate within the castle, he could briefly cancel the charm, then reinstate it.  Additionally, Fawkes' abilities to carry him, as described in HBP, are close enough to apparition (at least as described) as to make no difference.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the available excellent answers, there are two more points I would like raised:

First, it's a matter of respect for someone affected by an unknown (at the time) effect who may not come back from it. We know that to a degree doing things "the muggle way" is used as such, as when the Weasleys do their chores that could easily be solved with magic.

Valorum in the comments has another excellent example of this: "Harry refuses to use magic to dig Dobby's grave", which in particular is at quite analogous to the scene in question.

Secondly, as the magical effect is in fact unknown there is no telling how it will interact with other magic. This treatment is a precaution more than anything else.

Comment: You might want to mention that Harry refuses to use magic to dig Dobby's grave

Answer (score 2):

Could I just point out that it's probably a bit of a surprise to anyone if they find anyone unconscious (or petrified) on a normal evening. Not everyone is always 100% logical. I mean, if I found an unconscious person in a warehouse I probably wouldn't think "I'll load him onto that handcart over there".  Especially if, as everyone else points out, he was probably very close to the infirmary already.

Comment: Dumbledore doesn't strike me as the sort to get flustered at finding a (seemingly) dead body in a stairwell. Let's face it, it's apparently a rare year that at least a few of his charges aren't brutally murdered.